# Decomposição de Séries Temporais Diárias

Tags: r, séries-temporais

tenho uma série temporal de dados de vazão diários. Estou tentando decompor a ST para retirar as tendências e sazonalidades. Mas quando uso a função `decompose` o gráfico de sazonalidade aparece um borrão preto.

```
    QHE.ts <- ts(QUHE.z, freq = 365.25)
    QHE.ts.decom <- decompose(QUHE.ts, type = "mult")
    plot(QHE.ts)!
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o link para download dos dados: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwVpSqmgvCe-cHl0ZzJKYVZiVGs

Alguém sabe como tratar isso? Eu sei que há sazonalidade na vazão, pois existem diferentes períodos, úmido e seco durante o ano.

Comment: Isso é devido a algum comportamento da série. Tem como postar um gráfico dos dados, ou até mesmo disponibilizar ela?

Comment: Olá @Rcoster , obrigado pela resposta. Bom o gráfico acima é representativo dos dados. O primeiro gráfico são os dados observados, o segundo seria a tendência (trend), o terceiro a sazonalidade e o quarto o erro aleatório.

Comment: @BrunoMoreno sem os dados ou pelo menos parte deles que apresente o mesmo comportamento não tem como outras pessoas reproduzirem o gráfico e testarem alternativas. Pode ser também que algo esteja fora do formato "padrão" e leve ao comportamento.

Comment: @Molx obrigado or comentar. Eu tenho os dados em csv. Como faço para disponibilizá-lo?

Comment: @BrunoMoreno, tu tem uma conta google? Da para colocar no google drive e disponibilizar

Comment: @Molx o link foi disponibilizado. Obrigado.

Comment: Bruno, seu arquivo no Google Drive não está público, ele informa que é necessário pedir permissão ao autor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não postou seu código completo, segue o que eu usei com seus dados e deu um resultado aparentemente correto.

```
dados <- read.csv2("Vazao_UHE.csv")

dados.ts <- ts(data=dados$FURNAS, frequency = 365.25)
dados.ts.dec <- decompose(dados.ts, type="mult")

plot(dados.ts.dec)
```

O gráfico foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei os mesmos parâmetros que você, então talvez o seu problema esteja apenas na leitura dos dados. A imagem que você postou está pequena, mas o gráfico da tendência está bem diferente do que obtive, então os dados estão diferentes de alguma forma.

#### Edit

Reparei agora que o eixo X na sua figura parece ir de - até 4000 - indício de que realmente a série temporal foi criada de uma forma estranha. Se você quiser melhorar o eixo X, pode usar:

```
dados$Data <- as.Date(dados$Data, format="%d/%m/%Y")

dados.ts <- ts(data=dados$FURNAS, frequency = 365.25,
               start=as.integer(format(min(dados$Data), "%Y")))

#decompose() e plot()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Bruno,

Acredito que o erro esteja no comando utilizado, pois o que tu nos passou utiliza uma variável para criar a série (`QHE.ts`) e outra para a decomposição (`QUHE.ts`). Tente:

```
QHE.ts <- ts(QUHE.z, freq = 365.25)
QHE.ts.decom <- decompose(QHE.ts, type = "mult")
plot(QHE.ts.decom)
```

Comment: realmente o código está errado, mas não isso que faz com que a sazonalidade fique um borrão preto.

Comment: Esse problema não ocorreu para mim (e nem para o Molx)... é exatamente a mesma série que tu está utilizando? Se sim, reinstala o teu R e tenta novamente